# Why spring security need authorities collection be sorted?

Tags: java, spring-security

There is in UserDetails interface description has this requirement for function getGrantedAuthorities:

> Returns: the authorities, sorted by natural key (never null)

Why this condition is required? Should I implement it in GrantedAuthoritiesMapper?

Answer (score 2):

It is because of [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-717). Two users should be equal if their authorities and all other data are the same.

In practice it probably doesn't matter. If you don't actually make use of the equality check anywhere then you won't see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. It is for authentication token generation.